# How to override mutable property from a superclass

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ArcaneCardVC: UIViewController {
    var currentCard: ArcaneCardView?
}

class PostVC: ArcaneCardVC {    
    override var currentCard: PostCard? 
// <===== This is what I want to do but cant
}

class ArcaneCardView: UIView {

}
class PostCard: ArcaneCardView {

}
```

Here is the error I get:

> Cannot override mutable property 'currentCard' of type 'ArcaneCardView?' with covariant type 'PostCard?'

The other solution is explicitly doing this in code everytime I use currentCard:

```
var card = currentCard as! PostCard
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct way to do it is the way you're doing with `currentCard as! PostCard`.

Another option would be to use a property getter like

```
// inside PostVC

// Note the camel case on the 'C' makes it a different variable that the super class
var CurrentCard: PostCard {
    get { return self.currentCard as! PostCard }
}
```

Then you'd use `self.CurrentCard` instead of `self.currentCard as! PostCard`

Comment: Unsafe unwrapping is never the correct of doing something in Swift

Comment: Agreed, my answer here is not a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

When you override a variable, you can't change it's type. Why not? Well, suppose that you are able to do that, then the following scenario would be possible:

```
var A: PostVC = PostVC() // some initialization 
var B: ArcaneCardVC = A // this is a valid state since `PostVC` is a subclass of `ArcaneCardVC`
```

What should be the type of `B.currentCard`? Hmm, this is a complicated question. You can answer that its type should be `PostCard`. Ok, lets add other classes to the party:

```
class OtherCard: ArcaneCardView {

}

class OtherVC: ArcaneCardVC {    
    override var currentCard: OtherCard?      
}
```

Considerer now the following code:

```
var A: ArcaneCardVC = PostVC()
var B: ArcaneCardVC = OtherVC()
A.currentCard = B.currentCard // something will crash here!!!
```

To avoid this kind of behavior, you can't change the type of a property when you are subclassing.

Comment: Question was "How to..." but you are responding as if someone asked "Why its not possible to" ...

Comment: The title of the question refers to something but the actual problem in the code is completely unrelated. This answer addresses the problem in the code. Maybe I should've made it explicit...